# How to get do_shortcode() to stop stripping contents of a shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have wp job manager installed and i have  `echo do_shortcode( '[jobs]' );` in side a custom template but for some unknown reason the shortcode won't output the required results of the [jobs] shortcode.

But when i use the shortcode in the wp editor it works fine, i have been at this for hours and cant seem to find a solution tot his problem any where.

If you have encountered this issue before please advise me how you fixed it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the problem is you are doing do_shortcode before register_shortcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i had a javacript error in the browser console that's why do_shortcode() was not working correctly. I hope this helps someone else